# Display wordpress post from JSON in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, wordpress

Background: my app is an extension to a wordpress blog. It downloads a json containing the blog articles, parses them into individual articles (title, id, thumbnail, content) then displays them in a tableView. This part all works and looks nice.

Problem: Im looking into a good looking way to present the articles when the user taps one from the tableView. I would like it too look something like TUAW's or BGR's apps but I'm stuck -_- I would also like to keep the article formatting as intact as possible.

Libraries in use: SBJSON, ASIHTTPRequest, SDWebImage

Any advice

```
- (void)loadMyArticleData
{
    //create the beginning of the html string
    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"<html><head><title></title></head><body style=\"background:transparant;\">"];

    // Remove the iframe junk that wordpress has
    NSString *htmlText = [myArticle objectForKey:@"content"];
    NSRange range1 = [htmlText rangeOfString:@"<iframe"];
    NSRange range2 = [htmlText rangeOfString:@"</iframe>"];
    if (range1.location != NSNotFound && range2.location != NSNotFound) {
    htmlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                [htmlText substringToIndex:range1.location],
                [htmlText substringFromIndex:(range2.location+range2.length)]];
    }


   // finish our html code
   [html appendString:htmlText];
   [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

   //make the background transparent
   [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://leimobile.com"];

   //pass the string to the webview
   [webView loadHTMLString:[html description] baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

Heres an example post
http://pastie.org/3161382    (Sorry, it would have been extremely ugly to post here)

Answer (score 0):

What about a VC with a WebView and then set the content of that WebView to your content element in the post?  You could also add in your own custom CSS rules to format things the way you want them (like a tags, text size, etc).

Comment: Thats what i have going on right now but i know theres a better way to do this that involves keeping the text formatting, images sized properly and Videos if any. Thats what the -(void)loadMyArticleData does, it takes the content element and makes it an html string, strips out some junk, then loads it into the webview. But images are their true sizes and youtube videos (if any) are hidden completely

Comment: Why not add CSS directives to size images and other elements like you want?

Comment: think you can help me with an example? email is truehybridx at gmail.com. if we figure something out we can post it back on here

Comment: Well it will depend on what sizes you want to display.  For example if you want the images to be 100X150, then use a directive like this: img {height: 100; width: 150px}.

Comment: hmm im guessing my webview isn't finding the .css I have included in my project... http://pastie.org/3163733 is what my CSS looks like right now and http://pastie.org/3163740 is the function I'm using in the VC class to put the HTML together

Comment: Ok i managed to get my app to see the local CSS now.. it seems to ignore the img directive though.. but its a step closer

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (assume you already create a tableView which works fine right)

1)  Create a ViewController with title, image and content dynamically. This way you can hide anything if you don't have data for it.

2)  Use cellForRowAtIndexPath you know which cell got selected

3) Use PushView to bring  ViewController you create.

4) Load all the values in it.

Comment: I think what he is asking is how would be a good way to present and style that html string?

Comment: Thanks but that was the original problem, doing it this way only means one image from the article can be displayed, and the text formatting is removed -_-